# Is there a native Javascript implementation of jQuery's document.ready()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 $(document).onload()
```

it's internally implemented by window.onload event

then what about

```
 $(document).ready()
```

what's the native javascript to implement it?

Comment: jQuery *is* native JavaScript...

Comment: @shog9 +1 I came here to say that.

Comment: @Shog9: don't be difficult, you know what it means. :P

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For Mozilla, Opera and webkit, jQuery binds the [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko-Specific_DOM_Events) event, for IE jQuery uses the [onreadystatechange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536957%28VS.85%29.aspx) event.

Look the internal bindReady function on the [jQuery source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.3.2/src/event.js#L620).

Comment: The DomContentLoaded link is dead

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean?

.ready() is a function jQuery wrote to handle the inconsistent way that all the browsers may report 'load complete' for the given element.

.onload() may work in X browser but not Y. This is (part) of what jQuery is for - to solve this problem for you.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the jQuery source code, there is a function called `bindReady` that does the native Javascript work. There are different methods for different browsers, and the fallback method if none of the specific methods work is to use the `window.onload` event.