# how to check DOM is ready using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom

i am using this script in my jsp. some time when i click on that particular **button** it works fine but some time it doesn't work and show **Script Error : document.form is null not an object**. what ever i searched i found that document is not **finished loading** when i call **reset.**  how can i check whether the document has **loaded or not?**

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function closeWarning(){

      document.forms[0].reset();

    }
  </script>
</head>

<body onLoad="closeWarning();" 
 <jsp:include flush="true" page="/myCart/header.jsp"/>
 <div>
 // content of body
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate. Check http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=dom+ready

Comment: There is no button in your example, and I think you've already given the answer: the DOM tree is ready when the BODY element's ONLOAD event has triggered.

Comment: Duplicate. Check [Is there a native Javascript implementation of jQuery's document.ready()?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1283445/617996)

Comment: @ Simon Richter, thanks for response. i want to ask How can i check that   DOM is ready ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use jQuery, you can use an event listener for [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko-Specific_DOM_Events), as in:

`if(document.addEventListener) document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",closeWarning,false);`

This will work for everyone except IE, which uses [onreadystatechanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536957%28VS.85%29.aspx), as in:

`document.onreadystatechange=function() { if(this.readyState=="complete") { closeWarning();
        }
    }`

Comment: thanks cegfault ,now it is not showing script error, but content of the body is  loading till the first line of <body> tag. and pages remains blank

Answer (score 0):

One way is using jQuery and it's [ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function.