# Keypress function in native javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is my code:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e){
  var s = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
  if ( s === "f"){
    alert ("its f");
  }
  else if ( s === "r"){
    alert ("its r");
  }
});
```

I wanna do this in JavaScript...........!!

How can i do this ?

Comment: Why is the title "Document ready function in native javascript" ?

Comment: Not sure why he titled it "document ready" to begin with either, but this post would answer that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283445/is-there-a-native-javascript-implementation-of-jquerys-document-ready

Answer (score 9):

```
document.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) { 
  var key = e.keyCode || e.which;
  ... // rest of code
});
```

Comment: Both key event properties are [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode), use [keydown](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keydown_event)(pressed) and keyup (released).

Answer (score 2):

In native js you can attach events, via onClick, onKeyPress, ... etc element attributes.
Do not forget, the event parameter in the event handler function ;)
In different browsers, you can read the code of pressed key via different attribute of the event.

Here is an example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].onkeypress=function(e){
       var s = String.fromCharCode(e.which | evt.witch );
       switch(s){
           case "f":
              alert("key is 'f'");
              break;
           ....
       }
   };
</script>
```

Or You can use the `addEventListener` method, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].addEventListener('keypress',function(e){
       var s = String.fromCharCode(e.which | evt.witch );
       switch(s){
           case "f":
              alert("key is 'f'");
              break;
           ....
       }
     });
</script>
```

You should run these scripts after document loaded. You can subscribe the `domready` event like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", function(){
           //your code here  (one of the above)
       }, false );
</script>
```

This last section is discussed here: [javascript domready?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206937/javascript-domready). Unfortunetly you can subscribe domready event different ways depends on the client browser.

A sugggestion (offtopic):

There is a bunch of problems when you use native javascript, because of the browser's uncombatibilities, what is already resolved in `jQuery`. If you want to use `jQuery`, but you can not access the html code, and you want to load `jQuery` You can include `jQuery` to your site from the `CDN` url, with javascript too, like this:

```
<script>  
   (function() {
        var jQ = document.createElement('script'); jQ.type = 'text/javascript'; 
        jQ.async = true;
        jQ.src = '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(jQ, s);
   })();
</script>
```

As the google makes in analitycs code ;)

Comment: Cannot set property 'onkeypress' of undefined

Comment: did you paste the code the end of the document? Did your code run after domready event? I edit this, to show how to run after domready.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  document.onkeypress = keyPressFunction;

    function keyPressFunction(e) {
      var s = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
        if ( s === "f"){
         alert ("its f");
        }
        else if ( s === "r"){
         alert ("its r");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined

Comment: @EnterJQ i updated my code check it once

Answer (score 0):

heres a simple function that do exactly what you want -

```
document.onkeydown=function(e){
    var char= String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
    if(char=='f'){
        alert(char);
    }else if(char=='r'){
        alert(char);
    }
}
```