# Native JavaScript document.ready - How to use bindReady()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for a native JavaScript solution to jQuery's document.ready(). Looking at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1283456/1179449), CMS suggested to just use the [code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.3.2/src/event.js#L620) that jQuery used to implement their document.ready(). I am looking at `bindReady()` but am unsure how I would incorporate that into my code. I currently have something such as:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    console.log('foo');
});
```

Comment: You could try `window.onload = function(){}`, that might be good enough for you.

Comment: @RocketHazmat From my understanding, `window.onload` is fired only after all elements (including images) have finished loading. `$(document).ready()` is fired only when the HTML has finished loading. As I have a lot of large images on my page, I don't want my users to wait for the images to load before running my script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically when you need to do is replace the lines that have

```
jQuery.ready();
```

with the name of the function you want to call. If you want something that works like jQuery's ready registering method, build a function that makes a queue. Loop through the queue when the "ready" is triggered.

---

You asked for more info so here is a quick and dirty example not using a timeout. This is NOT production ready, just a basic POC.

```
    (function () {

        var ready = {
            _readyQueue: [],
            _hasRun: false,
            _docReadyCalled : function() {
                this._hasRun = true;
                this._execute();
            },
            _execute: function () {
                var func;
                while (this._readyQueue.length) {
                    func = this._readyQueue.shift();
                    func();
                }
            },
            register: function (func) {
                this._readyQueue.push(func);
                if (this._hasRun) {
                    this._execute();
                }
            }         
        }

        window.docReady = ready.register.bind(ready);  //use what ever global namespace you want here

        function bindReady() {

            /* This would be that jQuery code, I am just use window load here so not so much code */

            //Not all browser support this, quick and dirty for example
            window.addEventListener('load', ready._docReadyCalled.bind(ready), false);

        }

        bindReady();

    })();


    /* waiting for DOM to be ready */
    docReady(function () { console.log("here"); });
    docReady(function () { console.log("there"); });

    /* Showing what happens when you call docReady after it is ready */
    docReady(function () { console.log("registering ready again"); docReady(function () { console.log("I am here!"); });    });
```

Comment: Sorry, I do not quite follow. Can you explain with an example?

Comment: What do you need explained? replacing the `jQuery.ready();` lines or building a simple queue. :)

Comment: So in my example, would I do something like: `function foo() { console.log('foo'); }`? Then I would build a queue with `setInterval()` that will continuously check to see if `$(document).ready()` is ready?

Comment: If so, is there an alternative to using `setInterval()`?

Comment: I added a quick and dirty example, it could be a lot better, just wanted to show you the basic idea.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to probably avoid using DOM events entirely. It gets really complicated when you want to load as early as possible **but** want to be certain it isn't *too* early. This is an easy and 100% reliable technique to execute code as soon as the DOM has completed loading:

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- head content, blah, blah, blah -->
    <script>
        var ready = function() {
            // Put everything in this function that you want to run when the page loads
            nowTheDomIsLoaded();
            console.log('foo');
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- page content, blah, blah, blah -->
    <script>ready();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically you put everything you want run in a function (e.g. `ready()`) and the very last thing you do before the closing `</body>` tag is you execute that function. Because everything in the `<body>` has been parsed you know the DOM is loaded, and this doesn't take any special library.