# How to add event listener to not-yet existing elements (without jQuery)?

Tags: javascript

Here is the scenario I simplified:

I am trying to access an image link in, say, page "A". So my script opens page "A". But it's not that simple. Due to various reasons (i.e. login credentials, redirection), I cannot just use

```
window.open(url).getElement...
```

because what I get here does not contain the target image I want.

One way I could (which I did) do this is by setting

```
window.open(url).onload=function(){//get the image};
```

that is, I can get the image when the page is fully loaded (thus including the redirection).

My question then is, is there a way to have something that accomplishes`element.onload` when the element has NOT yet existed? **In this scenario, it would be to get the image URL without waiting for the image to load completely.**

Comment: It seems you are looking for the DOM ready event. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/1283445/218196

Comment: Have you read about the image object?

Answer (score 0):

The image object is good for this.
Just put this function where you'd like to load an image.

```
function loadImageInto(id){
    var image = new Image(); 
    image.onload = function(){
        document.getElementById(id).src = image.src;
    };
    image.src = "imagefile.jpg";
}
```

If you want an event handler you can do this.

```
function loadImageInto(id){
    return function(){
        var element = this;
        if(typeof id !== 'undefined'){
            element = document.getElementById(id);
        }
        var image = new Image(); 
        image.onload = function(){
            element.src = image.src;
        };
        image.src = "imagefile.jpg";
    }
}
```

This of course will only work if you know the image url ahead of time.